# I don't understand De Rham's theorem about the gradient of a distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, fluid-dynamics

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open
- $\mathcal D(\Omega):=C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ and $$\mathfrak D(\Omega):=\left\{\Phi\in\mathcal D(\Omega)^d:\nabla\cdot\Phi=0\right\}$$

In a [paper](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~wxm/paper/Wang_pressure.pdf), I've found the following theorem: Let $f\in\mathcal D'(\Omega)^d$ $\Rightarrow$ $$\left.f\right|_{\mathfrak D(\Omega)}=0\;\Leftrightarrow\;\exists p\in\mathcal D'(\Omega):f=\nabla p\;.\tag 1$$ This statement can be found in various books related to the study of the Navier-Stokes equations.

However, $(1)$ is obviously nonsense, cause by definition $f$ is a mapping $\mathcal D(\Omega)\to\mathbb R^d$ and the elements of $\mathfrak D(\Omega)$ are elements of $\mathcal D(\Omega)^d$, i.e. $\left.f\right|_{\mathfrak D(\Omega)}$ is an undefined symbol sequence.

So, at a first glance I thought they possibly mean $\left(\mathcal D(\Omega)^d\right)'$ instead of $\mathcal D'(\Omega)^d$. However, they write $f=(f_1,\ldots,f_d)$ in the paper (what suggests that $f$ is an $\mathbb R^d$-valued mapping) and by definition $\nabla p$ is a mapping $\mathcal D(\Omega)^d\to\mathbb R$.

> So, my question is: How do I need to interpret this theorem?

Comment: I think $f \in (\mathcal D(\Omega)^d)'$ so that $f_i :\mathcal D(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f(u) =\sum_{i=1}^d f_i(u_i)$ where $u \in \mathcal D(\Omega)^d$. overall $f : D(\Omega)^d \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @user1952009 Is any element of $(\mathcal D(\Omega)^d)'$ of this special form or is this a restriction?

Comment: what do you think ?

Comment: @user1952009 I could imagine that this is the case.

Comment: yes. for any $v \in D(\Omega)$, consider $P_i : D(\Omega) \to D(\Omega)^d$ such that $P_i(v)_i =v$, and $P_i(v)_j = 0$ for the others indices $j \ne i$. Any $u \in D(\Omega)^d$ is of the form $u = \sum_{i=1}^d P_i(u_i)$ so $f(u) = \sum_{i=1}^d f(P_i(u_i))$. And clearly $f(P_i(v)) = f_i(v)$ for some $f_i \in D(\Omega)'$. Overall $f(u) = \sum_{i=1}^d f_i(u_i)$

Comment: @user1952009 I'm surprised that in various books we find the statement with $f\in\mathcal D'(\Omega)^d$. Is this a usual (bad) notation for $(\mathcal D(\Omega)^d)'$ in distribution theory?